# Merge objects and get max value for each property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, reduce

I have to reduce an object of objects and get just 1 object with the max values for each property, for example

My input object is:

```
input: {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
}
```

and the final object must to have:

```
output:{
 "prop1": {
   "x": 88, //because is max on 2.0 object
   "y": 324 //because is max on 1.0 object
 },
 "prop2": {
   "x": 99,
   "y": 509
  },
 "prop3": {
   "x": 3,
   "y": 22
  },
 "prop4": {
   "x": 4,
   "y": 25
  },
}
```

The idea is to get for each property between multiple objects the max value between them and get 1 final object with all properties with the max value between all objects. Thanks in advance

```
Currently I trying with a reduce and then a foreach but I cant get the final result correctly.

Object.values(input).reduce((highestValues, objData) => {
  Object.entries(objData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const highest = highestValues[key]; 
    if (highest === undefined || highest > value) {
      highestValues[key] = value
    }
  })
  return highestValues
}, {});
```

Comment: initial glance - shouldn't that be `|| highest < value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const data = { "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(data).reduce((carry, current) => {
    Object.entries(current).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([k,v]) => {
            if (!carry[key]) {
                carry[key] = {}
            }
            carry[key][k] = Math.max(carry[key][k], v);
        });
    });
    return carry;
}));
```